# iOS 7 Cannot See Status bar (Signal , Time, Battery) When I Fixed Navigation Bar overlap TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

I fix problem iOS 7, Navigation Bar is Overlap Table View.

I use this Code

```
//for help navigation bar overlap
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```

I can fix this problem but navigation bar overlap status bar not show signal battery time same this picture:

[image: overlap]

Comment: Did you hide status bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your status bar is visible but your status bar text color is black so you can't see properly. if you just see from upside of your mac screen you can see this.

So follow the smita's answer is current but after change in **plist** you need to change it `statusBar` style with `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` that change to your statusbar text color black to white.

[image]

In to your image that already display that clock time signal or battery status. with black color and your navigation bar tint color already black so that both are match. that's why you can not see that.

But only setting this line of code not enough.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

You need to change in to plist like

- add one row with `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` set to **NO**. like bellow

[image]

now run you project that your navigation and statusbar look like:-

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In your AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOption method add this line of code -

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
```

May this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

In IOS7, if you want status bar depending on the view controller you can set the "View controller-based status bar appearance" in info-plist to "YES".

Override following method in all your controller to decide whether your that view need status bar or not.

```
  -(BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
```